# Confluent Kafka JDBC sink connector gives error Data truncation: Out of range value for column

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using confluent kafka platform to read data from a database "A" and insert it to another database "B" (both mysql).
Everything worked fine for a few weeks, but today I'm getting an error "Out of range value for column" when the JDBC sink connector tries to insert the data in database "B".

Sink connector config:

```
{
  "name": "connector_name",
  "config": {
    "name": "connector_name",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "transforms": "unwrap",
    "topics": "topic_name",
    "topics.regex": "",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://server_name:12345?useSSL=false",
    "connection.user": "db_user",
    "connection.password": "****************",
    "connection.attempts": "5",
    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "table.types": "PARTITIONED TABLE, TABLE",
    "pk.mode": "record_value",
    "pk.fields": "id, data",
    "fields.whitelist": "",
    "auto.create": "true",
    "auto.evolve": "true",
    "quote.sql.identifiers": "always"
  }
}
```

The error is about a BIGINT field (with default value to NULL on database side): checking the message inside the topic the value is actually NULL, so I don't understand why I get this error.
Can anyone help please?
Thank you

Tried to:

- Re-create the connector --> didn't work
- Insert the row manually --> worked fine
- Check table configuration --> is the same on both databases